# Why am I not getting result for dynamic created TRs?

Tags: jquery, html

the following code works just great for trs there are in the html

JS Fiddle:  [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/1bwpqL6n/)

```
            var data = [];
            table.find('tr.trMyRow').each(function (rowIndex, r) {
                var cols = [];
                $(this).find('th,td').each(function (colIndex, c) {

                    $(this).find("input.classKey").each(function (inputIndex, j){
                        console.log(j);
                    });

                    $(this).find("input.classValue").each(function (input2Index, g){
                        console.log(g);
                    });

                    cols.push(c.textContent);
                });
                data.push(cols);
            });
```

but when the trs are dynamically created ones from `.append("<tr class='trMyRow'>etc...")`  it is not retrieved by the selector, any ideas?

Comment: Where are you running this code in your application? Is it part of a larger function? Is it run only after page load? Is it run again after the table rows are created dynamically?

Comment: the jquery code is at the body of my page, and yes it runs after the dynamically created rows

Comment: Are you really appending your tables with this exact code?  `.append("<tr>etc...")` or are you making sure to add the class name like this? `.append("<tr CLASS="tbMyTable">etc...")?`

Comment: there is only one table element and it is not dynamic. the append for trs contains the trMyTable class. It is very frustrating that it doesnt' work with dynamic ones

Comment: You have to make sure you code is accurate for us to help you. Please update this part of your question `append("<tr>etc...")`. And `table.find` is not valid code. Have you tried using `$('table').find`?

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle?

Comment: I'm just doing it now

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, you are putting wrong class. The appended tr has class trMetadata while you are looking for class trMyRow. check here: http://jsfiddle.net/1bwpqL6n/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add tbMyTable class to appended tr `.append("<tr class='tbMyTable'>etc...")`.